# Is a free non-commutative ring Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the free ring $R = \mathbb{Z}\left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right>$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are non-commuting intermediates. Is the ring $R$ Noetherian?

More generally, let $S$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Is the non-commutative ring $R_S = S\left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right>$ Noetherian?

(In some sense, this question is asking for a non-commutative variant of Hilbert's basis theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not Noetherian.  Even for any field, $k\langle x,y\rangle$ is known to be neither left nor right Noetherian, and you have quotients of this ring that produce such ring (say, the quotient by the ideal $(2)$.) This ring cannot be right Noetherian because it would mean the quotient would be right Noetherian.

One way to see it is not Noetherian is that you can take the quotient by $xy-1$ and have a ring where $x$ has a one-sided inverse. This is not possible in a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Thank you @rschwieb. I was able to find hints at why Noetherianity implies (left invertible is invertible) on this website, including some of your answers!

Comment: @the_lar No problem. Could you link them in the comments here? I was having trouble finding them.

Answer (score 3):

As a more direct alternative to the nice slick answer of @rschweib, $R=\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ is not right Noetherian, as it has an ascending chain
$$x_1R < x_1R+x_2x_1R < x_1R+x_2x_1R+x_2^2x_1R
<\dots$$
of right ideals.

Or, equivalently, the right ideal generated by
$$x_1, x_2x_1, x_2^2x_1,\dots$$
(which in the case $n=2$ is the same as the two-sided ideal generated by $x_1$) is not finitely generated as a right ideal.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy for the direct and clear proof (which is always great). I would accept it if I hadn't already accepted @rschwieb).